# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError PYTHON

Tags: python, json, decoder

I am currently processing a json database and for now I have a file containing 10000 json lines like this:

```
{"name": "Khau0304lid Muhu0323ammad u02bbAliu0304 al-Hu0323au0304jj", "personal_name": "Khau0304lid Muhu0323ammad u02bbAliu0304 al-Hu0323au0304jj", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:57:09.66187"}, "key": "/authors/OL1000057A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
{"name": "K. Hardono", "personal_name": "K. Hardono", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-09-08T16:19:17.29978"}, "key": "/authors/OL100029A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
{"name": "Nuu0304r al-Diu0304n Su0323ammuu0304d", "personal_name": "Nuu0304r al-Diu0304n Su0323ammuu0304d", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:58:34.686964"}, "key": "/authors/OL1000624A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
{"name": "Mawlu016bd Qu0101sim Nu0101yit Bulqu0101sim", "personal_name": "Mawlu016bd Qu0101sim Nu0101yit Bulqu0101sim", "created": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-04-01T03:28:50.625462"}, "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2017-11-10T08:11:59.146669"}, "latest_revision": 3, "key": "/authors/OL1000703A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 3}
{"name": "Ali Ak", "personal_name": "Ali Ak", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T17:59:35.453547"}, "key": "/authors/OL1001014A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
{"name": "Nazamiu0304 Rau0304majiu0304", "personal_name": "Nazamiu0304 Rau0304majiu0304", "last_modified": {"type": "/type/datetime", "value": "2008-08-20T18:00:41.270799"}, "key": "/authors/OL1001461A", "type": {"key": "/type/author"}, "revision": 2}
```

I manage to recover most of the information but on the 10,000 lines there are some which are in incorrect format.

I get an error like this:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 148 (char 147)
```

And here is my code that works on the correct lines:

```
import json


with open('openlibrarytest.json') as file:
    for i in range(9998):
        line = file.readline()
        content_json = json.loads(line)
        if not "name" in line:
            # print('NULL')
            ligne.append("NULL")
            continue
        try:
            # print(content_json['name'])
            ligne.append(content_json['name'])
        except IndexError:
            print(line)
```

So for the best I would like to be able to have all the information even on the incorrect lines so act as if we ignored the error and we recover the information anyway on the line.

Or another alternative would be to ignore the line where there is the error and continue to browse my file.

Do not hesitate to ask me questions if it is not clear.

Thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: You should catch the error and `print()` the lines that cause it. Only then can we start to understand how the format got messed up and consider how we can get around it